# Lua -- substring

Tags: string, lua

I have something like

```
 a = "6ff"
 b = "144f"
```

and must change the string into

```
 "6ff"  -> "6--8"   
 "144f" -> "144--145"
```

In short (n is a natural number): Replace `"nff"` by `"n--n+2"` and `"nf"` by `"n--n+1"`
I tried with searching for "ff", extracting the number and so on. But I have no idea how to do it with pattern matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function fix(s)
    local n,f=s:match("(%d+)(f+)")
    if n==nil then
        return s
    else
        n=tonumber(n)
        f=#f
        return n.."--"..(n+f)
    end
end

print(fix("144f"))
print(fix("6ff"))
print(fix("6"))
```